# How can I solve the input shape issue in CNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am using to classify  the handwritten characters and following my CNN model.
I have converted the images to gray scale and binarized.
How can I solve this problem?

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=10,kernel_size=(3,3),padding = 'same', input_shape=(100, 100, 3),activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(30,(5,5),activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(40,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(60,(3,3),activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(180,activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

model.add(layers.Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(12,activation='softmax'))
```

Error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_41 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 100, 100]
```

Comment: What is your input? Can you please provide a minimal working example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your model you've stated the input shape to be `(100,100,3)`. The model is expecting a 3 channel image but you've said your input data is grayscale, meaning that it only has one channel. This means that your input data is of the shape `(100,100,1)`, which then is just `(100,100)`. With the addition of the `batch_size` dimension it becomes `[None,100,100]` which is the error you are getting.

Changing the input shape to `(100,100,1)` should do the trick.

Comment: After changing ```(100,100,1)``` again the error occurs ```ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_43 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 100, 100]```  Here layer sequential _41 changed to 42

Comment: Then it means the input data is not in the `ndarray` format, probably still in the image format. What does your input look like?

Comment: ```x = [];

y = [];

for folder in names:

  files = os.listdir("/dataset/"+folder);

  for file in files:

    img = image.load_img("/dataset/"+folder+"/"+file,target_size=(100,100));

    img = image.img_to_array(img);

    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    img = (img > 150) * 255;

    x.append(img);
    y.append(names.index(folder))

x = np.array(x);
y = np.array(y)```